# Why is the greek letter Pi used for Pi (product) notation?

Tags: notation, pi

We are learning about it and my teacher didn't explain why either Sigma nor Pi were used.

Comment: I'm really not sure but to me Sum starts with and "S" and Product with a "P". See the connection ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why sigma notation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401613/why-sigma-notation) For product see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620187/what-does-the-prod-symbol-mean).

Answer (score 3):

It's phonetic - $\Sigma$ stands for "sum" and $\Pi$ stands for "product.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ is a capital letter from the Greek alphabet called “Pi", it corresponds to “P” in our alphabet. So, "p"roduct notation is derived from the symbol of "Pi", $\pi$.
A similar reasoning holds for the summation symbol, sigma.